# group the results of a matching function

Tags: excel, libreoffice-calc, openrefine

i have three columns in excel, one that holds the row id, the next one a product serial number, and the last one again some serial numbers.

```
098 11079851   11079851
110 11089385   25853201
118 11089385   22412115
798 11079851   22412115
```

what i need to do, is to find if the value in column B, exists in column C. Then, i need to have a way, to have the values of column B, that were found in column C, grouped, along with their corresponding row ids.

example output of 11079851 that exists in column C:
 11079851: 098, 798 perhaps one cell had the row id, and the next ones, each one having a corresponding number from column B, that may be found in column C.

in excel this is what i use so as to get the existance of each cell's value of column B in column C:

```
=NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(B2,$C$2:$C$1000,0)))
```

since i do not have excel version required (even 2016 will not have textjoin), i tried the suggested formula from below answer,

```
=IF(COUNTIF($C$1:$C$4,B1),B1&": "&TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF($B$1:$B$4=B1,$A$1:$A$4,""))"")
```

but i get a 509 error. What am i missing?

Comment: Run your formula in a helper columns, then either sort or filter on that column

Comment: could you please elaborate? i have the helper formula in a fourth column, which returns TRUE for the row ids i want. But how do i group them to get the expected output? in a cell, i need such output: 11079851: 098, 798

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: i am using excel 2016, but still the TEXTJOIN function doesnot exist...

Answer (score 2):

Maybe in `D1`:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($C$1:$C$4,B1),B1&": "&TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF($B$1:$B$4=B1,$A$1:$A$4,"")),"")
```

Enter through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Drag down...

Note that this would work in Excel2016 or later with `TEXTJOIN()` enabled.

P.S. I don't have `TEXTJOIN()` myself and can't test if this works for you.

Comment: Just tested it and it looks like it works with the sample data.

Comment: Suggestion:  Return null string instead of `FALSE` for the non-matches

Comment: @JvdV i copy pasted the formula, in D1 cell, then pressed Ctrl+Shift+Enter. Then the cell is red, and nothing gets calculated, since 0ffice 365 reports that in D1 cell, there is an error

Comment: You probably also don't have TEXT JOIN enabled. See if this applies to you: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c

Comment: i have tested with office 365, and i find the TEXTJOIN function available for use

Comment: @openref, I unfortunately can't test. I see there was a missing `,` so added that. Does it work now for you?